# Select rows where a field is associated with more than one predefined value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had a hard time choosing a title for this question. I am not sure it describes accurately what I want, so I will be grateful if instead of a downvote you will help to improve the title. :)

I have the following (sample) tables:

```
USERS:
+----------+
|    id    |
+----------+
|     1    |
------------
|     3    |
------------
|     4    |
+----------+
URLS:
+----------+----------+
|    id    |    url   |
+----------+----------+
|     1    |   a.com  |
-----------------------
|     1    |   b.com  |
-----------------------
|     1    |   d.com  |
-----------------------
|     2    |   a.com  |
-----------------------
|     2    |   e.com  |
-----------------------
|     3    |   a.com  |
-----------------------
|     3    |   e.com  |
-----------------------
|     3    |   f.com  |
-----------------------
|     3    |   g.com  |
-----------------------
|     4    |   a.com  |
-----------------------
|     4    |   e.com  |
+----------+----------+
```

I want to select from `URLS` all the URL's that corresponds to at least two ids that are in `USERS`. So for eample, the result of such query with these sample table:

```
+----------+
|    url   |
+----------+
|   a.com  | <- associated with ids: 1, 3, 4
------------
|   e.com  | <- associated with ids: 3, 4
+----------+
```

As you can see, `b.com`, for example, is associated with `1` which is in the `USERS` table. However, because it is not associated with any other id in `USERS` then it is not in the result. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use STUFF() for what you want.

Comment: @ZekiGumus - Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I am preparing a sample now

Comment: Just do an inner join between the tables to limit to records with a matching ID in users then GROUP BY url and HAVING COUNT(1) > 1. Just lookup the HAVING clause and it should become apparent.

Comment: SO is not a free coding service website.  What have you tried???  Post your query.  If you haven't tried anything, get to work.

Comment: @EricJ.Price - could you please demonstrate your idea in an answer?

Comment: @Eric - No need for speaking this way. I have no idea how to approach this, so I ask. This is a concept I am asking about, not a request for free coding.

Comment: @Sipo I am providing the information in this manner because it is not appropriate to create a response for a very simple well documented situation. I am not trying to be rude, but if you search for HAVING on msdn you should get a myriad of examples that will work for you... SELECT ur.url FROM users u JOIN urls ur on u.id = ur.id GROUP BY ur.url HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ur.id) > 1 ... good luck

Comment: @Sipo This is simple enough problem for anyone to at least attempt to create a solution.  Clearly, this show no effort whatsoever.

Comment: @Eric - I do not know how to start approaching this. I cannot just write a random query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have more than one id associated with a `url` if the min does not equal the max for each, and we can exclude `ids` not in the `USERS` table by doing an `inner join`, so perhaps something like this

```
select url
from URLS as a
inner join USERS as b
on a.id=b.id
group by url
having max(b.id)<>min(b.id)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this would perform better or worse than a COUNT(DISTINCT id) > 1, but it would achieve the desired result. The only extra consideration is if there is no constraint between the ID column in urls with users then you would need to JOIN if you want to ignore records from URLS that don't have a matching USERS record.

Comment: To fill the exact wording of the question, the join to `Users` is needed.  Question asks for "URL's that corresponds to at least two ids that are in USERS".   Your code could return URLs that correspond to two ids even if they are not in `Users` at all.

Comment: @MattCremeens that would only be true if we can assume that all ids in `URLs` are also in `Users`, but in the sample data that is not the case.

Comment: @TabAlleman This is a valid point. I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS()` as

```
SELECT Url
FROM Urls T
WHERE EXISTS(
              SELECT 1
              FROM Urls
              WHERE ID != T.ID
                    AND
                    Url = T.Url
            )
GROUP BY Url;
```

Or

```
SELECT T1.Url
FROM Urls T1 JOIN Urls T2
ON T1.ID != T2.ID
AND T1.Url = T2.Url
GROUP BY T1.Url;
```

---

Update:

Since you need to join with `Users` table

```
SELECT T1.Url
FROM Urls T1 INNER JOIN Users T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE EXISTS(
              SELECT 1
              FROM Urls
              WHERE ID != T1.ID
                    AND
                    Url = T1.Url
            )
GROUP BY T1.Url;

SELECT T1.Url
FROM Urls T1 INNER JOIN Urls T2
ON T1.ID != T2.ID
AND T1.Url = T2.Url
INNER JOIN Users U ON T1.ID = U.ID
GROUP BY T1.Url;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6b8322467c9ce42de0301e8bb56eac3e)**

Comment: Thanks! But where in this select there is a check against the `USERS` table?

Comment: Alright @Sipo check the updates.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting 0 results. :(

Comment: Well, I don't think so @Sipo you can check the demo there.

Comment: You are right, I had a configuration issue. Let me test it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all associated Ids in same column you can use `STUFF()` . Here is your sample:

```
--DROP TABLE Users;
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    id  INT
);


--DROP TABLE Urls;
CREATE TABLE Urls
(
    id  INT
    ,Url    VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO Users VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4)
INSERT INTO URLs  VALUES
 (1,'a.com')
,(1,'b.com')
,(1,'d.com')
,(2,'a.com')
,(2,'e.com')
,(3,'a.com')
,(3,'e.com')
,(3,'f.com')
,(3,'g.com')
,(4,'a.com')
,(4,'e.com')

SELECT *,
        STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR)
                    from URLs U2
                    WHERE U1.Url=U2.Url
                    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Users US WHERE U2.id=US.id)
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Url FROM Urls) U1
```

Comment: I think OP just wants URL values that are associated with more than one User... I don't think they even care what the users are, just that there are multiple.

Comment: I have added EXISTS() to the stuff. So, now it is related with Users as well.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried your solution. I am getting all the URL's as a result, instead of only `a.com` and `e.com`.

Comment: @ZekiGumus I am pretty sure you have misunderstood the question.

Comment: @TabAlleman You are right. Anyway, it is already marked as duplicated. Thanks.